# Check if Google Play location service is enabled

Tags: android

How can I check if Google Play location services are enabled? None of the answers on StackOverFlow address the issue directly. I'm not interested in last location, whetever or not GPS and network providers are enabled in system or anything, I just want to know, if Google Play location services are enabled.

I tried using getLocationAvailability().isLocationAvailable(), but it returned true (after location was retrieved for first time) even after I disabled Google Play location services, which then prevented the application from working correctly.

Image of setting (first one on the image, ignore arrow):
http://img.wonderhowto.com/img/38/89/63522883742111/0/psa-googles-keeping-tabs-your-location-heres-stop-them.w654.jpg

Is there any way to check for this?

Comment: From the picture above, what you want to check is if **Location History** is enabled, not Google Play Location Services

Comment: I mean the first setting on this image. I just used a random image from internet.

Comment: That option does not appear to exist on the Google Settings app on my Nexus 4, running Android 5.1. That screenshot is from an older edition of that app (Holo theme, instead of Material).

Comment: Did you try adding a connectionfailedListener when initializing GoogleApiClient. I think the failed listener should get called when app cannot connect.

Comment: Application can connect to Google API even if above setting is disabled.